# Using a c++ dll within a c# project

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am hoping someone can help me. i have a dll file called LC4_Comm_Lib.dll which allows communication to a device, however im trying to use it in a c# project. Honestly i am unaware if this will work at all, the dll file came with a h file

```
    /*
=======================================================================================================================
INFO
=======================================================================================================================
Title       : LC4_Comm_Lib  - Function that are writen for LC4 
Author      : Slobodan Milosevic
Revision    : 1.0.0.1
Date        : 02.11.2015.
=======================================================================================================================
CHANGE LOG
=======================================================================================================================
1.0.0.0     : Initial Release
1.0.0.1     : Brasil update2
=======================================================================================================================
*/
#pragma once


/// Added to enforce __cdecl calling convetion
#define CALL __cdecl

#ifdef LC4_COMM_LIB_EXPORTS
#define COMMLIB_LC4_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define COMMLIB_LC4_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


typedef struct LC4SystemInformation{
    char CalibrationDate[64];
    char Calibrationvalidity;
    char BSMInumber[64];
    char LC4_fw[64];
    char PL4_fw[64];
    char PL4_checksum[64];
}LC4SystemInformation, *ptrLC4SystemInformation;

/* open usb communication */
long COMMLIB_LC4_API Open_USB_Comm();
/* open wifi communication */
long COMMLIB_LC4_API Open_WiFi_Comm(const char* ipAddress);
/* set encryption key */
long COMMLIB_LC4_API Set_Encryption_Key(const char* key);
/* decrypt encrypted file */
long COMMLIB_LC4_API Decrypt_File(const char* encryptedFilePath, const char* _decryptedFilePath);
/* create list of files */
long COMMLIB_LC4_API Create_Available_File_List(int type, const char* time, const char* listPath);
/* get file from device */
long COMMLIB_LC4_API Get_File(const char* Lc4_Path, const char* pc_Path, bool encFlag);
/* close communication whith LC4 device */
void COMMLIB_LC4_API Close_Comm();
/* power off LC4 device */
long COMMLIB_LC4_API Power_Down();
/* get system information */
long COMMLIB_LC4_API Get_SysInfo(ptrLC4SystemInformation sysInfo);
/* set settings path */
void COMMLIB_LC4_API Set_Settings_Path(const char* errorFilePath);
/* get error code*/
long COMMLIB_LC4_API Get_Error_Code();
/* get error string*/
size_t COMMLIB_LC4_API Get_Error_String(char* errStr);
/* get current file progres - for downloaded file */
size_t COMMLIB_LC4_API Get_File_Progress();
/* get size of file */
size_t COMMLIB_LC4_API Get_File_Size();
/* Serial Number */
int COMMLIB_LC4_API cmd_GetLidarSerialNo(char *);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I have got the communication to work in a C++ project however i was wondering if it is at all possible to get it to work in my c# project (guessing without the use of the h file). I have tried many things using DLLImport and even adding it through references, also

```
 [DllImport("LC4_Comm_Lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

I am not sure if i am wasting my time, so thought i would double check

Comment: `DllImport` is a good way to use a C++ project with C#. What are the errors you are seeing? Also, are the functions you are trying to use exported as `extern "C"`?

Comment: @rhughes The functions are all marked as ````extern "C"```` using a macro condition.

Comment: WTF are you calling a DLL written by a genocidal dictator??? Also, are you're C# methods ````static extern````?

Comment: *your. That mispelling really annoys me and I cannot let it stand.

Comment: I tried importing the function like this `[DllImport("LC4_Comm_Lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "Open_USB_Comm")] static extern long Open_USB_Comm();`  then calling it in my program like this `Open_USB_Comm()`  however didnt work and i get an error saying System.BadImageFormatException

Comment: @Vijay Yadav I guess it's not really incorrect in calling Slobodan Milosevic a bad image... Seriously though, why is Slobodan Milosevic listed as the author? Is it just some dummy value you put in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use C++ DLL in C# code without using your .h file. 
First of all you have to do DLL import. Here i am creating a class MFCdllConnector to do the operation.

> ```
> class MFCdllConnector
>  { 
>    [DllImport( "LC4_Comm_Lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl ) ]
>
>    public static extern <your exporting function> //please find below example
>    public static extern int  MyExampleExportFunction([MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string para1, [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string para2,[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] ref StringBuilder output);
>  }
>
> //You can call this function like below
> int return = MFCdllConnector.MyExampleExportFunction(para1, para2, ref OUTPUT);
> ```

Hope this will help